# Multiple file upload/submit forms

Tags: javascript, html

I have a single page with multiple file upload forms. Which are generated in loop.

Problem: first file upload control works, and the rest don't.

```
<div>
    <form action="/docs/1046/UploadDocument?Id=1046&amp;propertyTypeId=1" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
        <input name="X-HTTP-Method-Override" type="hidden" value="PUT">                                           
            <div style="display: none">           
                <label for="fileCOMMERCIAL_TRANSPORT_LICENSE"></label>                                       
                <input id="fileCOMMERCIAL_TRANSPORT_LICENSE" name="fileCOMMERCIAL_TRANSPORT_LICENSE" type="file" onchange=" $('#btnSubmitData').click(); ">
                <input id="btnSubmitData" type="submit" onclick=" txt = $('#fileCOMMERCIAL_TRANSPORT_LICENSE').val(); alert(txt); ">          
            </div>           
            <div>                  
                <label>
                    Document 1:
                </label>
                <button type="button" onclick=" $('#fileCOMMERCIAL_TRANSPORT_LICENSE').click(); ">Upload 1</button>
            </div>
    </form>
    <form action="/docs/1046/UploadDocument?Id=1046&amp;propertyTypeId=5" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
        <input name="X-HTTP-Method-Override" type="hidden" value="PUT">
            <div style="display: none">
                <label for="fileCLEAN_CRIMINAL_RECORD"></label>
                <input id="fileCLEAN_CRIMINAL_RECORD" name="fileCLEAN_CRIMINAL_RECORD" type="file" onchange=" $('#btnSubmitData').click(); ">
                    <input id="btnSubmitData" type="submit" onclick=" txt = $('#fileCLEAN_CRIMINAL_RECORD').val(); alert(txt); ">
            </div>
            <div>
                <label>
                    Document 2:
                </label>
                <button type="button" onclick=" $('#fileCLEAN_CRIMINAL_RECORD').click(); ">Upload 2</button>
            </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

[jsfiddle sample](http://jsfiddle.net/AlbertasA/5PgFg/1/):

Comment: The fiddle is at http://jsfiddle.net/AlbertasA/5PgFg. OP needs to edit their post and include code (not just the link).

Comment: I dont see any errors in your html code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your id #btnSubmitData  unique. That should fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what your problem is but sometimes make sure your input **has a different name**:

```
<form action="...">
    <input type="file" name="firstFile" />   //other names
    <input type="file" name="secondFile" />
    <input type="submit" value="send" />
</form>
```